# C# Select specific rows in existing Excel file

Tags: c#, excel

Hi I'd like to know how to highlight cells with same value in existing Excel file. My excel file contains more rows with names. I want highlight names what are equal as I use in textbox.

```
string workbookPath = @"PathOfExcelFile";
_Excel.Application ExcelApp = new _Excel.Application();
ExcelApp.Visible = true;
_Excel.Workbook workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath);
_Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;             

_Excel.Range selectRange;
selectRange = worksheet.get_Range(""); //
```

Thank you

Comment: foreach cell in range (if cell.Value == textbox.Text){///do what u want to do}

Comment: what do you mean as range ?? I understand that cell is string type what you want to find in excel. But what is range ? maybe I understand you wrong. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This is my proposal to highlight cells :

```
//find last cell if needed
            int lastCell = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(
                "*",
                System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
                Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole,
                Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
                false,
                System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Row;
            Excel.Range rangeCheck = xlWorkSheet.Range["A1:A" + lastCell];

            foreach (Excel.Range cell in rangeCheck.Cells)
            {
                string checkStrigng = Convert.ToString(cell.Value);//converts cell value to string for comparision
                if (checkString == textbox.Text)
                {
                    cell.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                }
            }
```